# How to edit a Phonegap/Cordova-project in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I built a Phonegap/Cordova iOS-app using the command line. I can run it with the CLI.

After that I'm using XCode to compile and run the project that was created in '`platforms/ios`' on the iOS simulator. This works too.

Now I would like to use XCode to make changes to the app. XCode does display a `www`-folder and `config.xml` but these are the top ones in the project folder , not in `platforms/ios`.

So if I change the files that are displayed in XCode, no changes appear when I run the project.

So, how can you edit a files of a Phonegap/Cordova project and run it with XCode ?   (and still being able to use the CLI, would be nice as well).

Answer (score 2):

You always need to modify the `project_folder/www` files. You can edit this files using Xcode, notepad++ or even with a simple notepad. Use what ever you like.

Then run the command using CLI

```
cordova build ios
```

Your project is now completely built. You can see the changes you made inside `platform/ios/.../www` files too. Now you can run the project using CLI or Xcode as wish. To run in CLI

```
cordova run ios
```

Or to emulate in emulator

```
cordova emulate ios
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right, you have to edit the root www folder.
Your problem is you have to do a `cordova prepare ios` to copy the changes from the root www folder to the `platform/ios/www` folder

You can do it from the cordova CLI or you can add a build script to you project (on build phases -> new Run Script phase) that runs the `cordova prepare ios` every time you run the project from xcode
The code you need on the scrip is

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/:/usr/local/bin
cordova prepare ios
```

Put it the first one

If you really want to edit the patform/ios/www folder, on xcode you will see a staging folder, there you have the www folder and the changes you do there are applied to the project, but when you do a `cordova prepare ios` that files will be replaced by the ones on the root www folder and you will lose all your work, so don't do that